# Using variables as object names and pushing arrays into objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, wordpress, object

I am building a WordPress plugin which allows users to recreate the WordPress admin menu. WordPress provides a global variable called `global $submenu;` which contains all the sub menu items of the menu. So I have developed a Javascript interface which allows people to edit this menu. So what I need to do is get the users edits and push it back into that global variable.

When I output this variable into the javascript console I get a structure like:

```js
    Object {index.php: Object, upload.php:Object}

      index.php: Object
        0: Array(3)
        0: "Home"
        1: "read"
        2: "index.php"

      10: Array(3)
        0: "Updates"
        1: "update_core"
        2: "update-core.php"
    
      upload.php: Object
        5: Array(3)
        0: "Library"
        1: "upload_files"
        2: "upload.php"

      10: Array(3)
        0: "Add New"
        1: "upload_files"
        2: "media-new.php"
```

This is a shortened example of the output just to give you an idea. So it contains an object which contains 2 objects, and those 2 objects contain 2 arrays each (those 2 object names are the index values which match up to an associated top level menu item, and the values in the arrays are the properties of the sub menu item).

So in Javascript I have a loop which gathers these object names i.e. index.php and upload.php and then I have a loop inside that loop which gathers the objects sub menu properties:

```js
$('#admin-menu-manager > li > ul').each(function(index) {
  //this gets the object name e.g. index.php or upload.php    
  var associatedTopLevelMenuItemLabel = $(this).parent().find('.menu-url').val();

  var $this = $(this);
  var $subLevelUl = $(this).find("li");

  $($subLevelUl).each(function(index) {
    //these below variables get the properties of the sub menu
    //menu item property 1
    var subLevelMenuItemLabel = $(this).find('.menu-label').val();
    //menu item property 2
    var subLevelMenuItemCapability = $(this).find('.menu-capability').val();
    //menu item property 3
    var subLevelMenuItemLink = $(this).find('.menu-url').val();
    //now I am creating an array to store the sub level properties
    var subLevelMenuItemArray = [subLevelMenuItemLabel, subLevelMenuItemCapability, subLevelMenuItemLink];

  });

});
```

The problem with this code is:
a) I don't know how to create an object that uses the variable 'associatedTopLevelMenuItemLabel' as it's name, and,
b) I don't know how to push these 'subLevelMenuItemArray' arrays into the object.

I know how to push an array into another array but I believe you can't push an array into this object. Is what I am trying to do even possible in Javascript or am I barking up the wrong tree here and I should use PHP?

Comment: **JavaScript object** it's just a *hashset* https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: Hi anete.anetes thanks for your comment, are you saying that I don't need to worry about actually creating objects and arrays I just need to create a string which looks like it's an object and an array? I am sorry, I am not familiar with a hashset, I am still learning. But I think what you are saying makes sense. Because I don't actually need to utilise the functions of javascript objects and arrays, I just need to make it look like it is I think.

Comment: yeah, you can access your properties of object by string `object['propname']`, and you can store your `propname` inside some variabe

Comment: Thanks, I am going to give this a go. It sounds like I was over thinking things way too much.

Comment: JavaScript easy language with great opportunities for shooting in the legs

Answer (score 0):

Thanks anete.anetes for your comments. I think in this instance I was trying to overthink things pretty significantly. Because I don't actually need to create real arrays or objects I should actually be just trying to create a string representation of an object. So I can just create a simple variable and ad to that variable with my existing loops. Then access these properties of that string if need be.